# Does Objective-C implicitly typecast NSMutableArrays to NSArrays when returned?

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsmutablearray

If I have a method like this:

```
-(NSArray *)methodThatReturnsAnArray;
```

And this is its implementation:

```
-(NSArray *)methodThatReturnsAnArray {

    NSMutableArray *aMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [aMutableArray addObject:@"some string"];
    return aMutableArray;
}
```

Will Objective-C implicitly cast `aMutableArray` to `NSArray` when it is returned, or do I have to specify that like this:

```
    return (NSArray *)aMutableArray;
```

Comment: @H2CO3 - That document helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so yes, you don't have to do the type cast. It's textbook [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism).

Answer (score 2):

As with [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29) in object oriented languages in general, since `NSMutableArray` extends from `NSArray` class it [**IS A**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `NSArray` at all effect.

You don't need to cast it to a `NSArray` because it is already a `NSArray`, or in practice, it is able to respond to all messages to which an `NSArray` could respond so [it can be used in replacement to it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the `NSMutableArray` object, since it's a subclass of `NSArray`.

Note that it will still be a mutable array however. Usually this isn't a problem, but if you want to make sure it's non mutable, you have to create a new instance or a copy.

```
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:aMutableArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

A cast doesn't change an object's type. It just tells the compiler it should assume it is a object of an certain type. But a `(NSArray *)aMutableArray` will still be a `NSMutableArray`.